# Перевести Spring Security XML Config в java класс

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Добрый день.
У меня есть конфигурация XML для Spring Security.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как перевести ее из XML в класс java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.hellokoding.account.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
      class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Спасибо.

Я перевел :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.
            jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}

@Autowired
protected void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
    registry
            .userDetailsService(getUserDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(gatPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PlaintextPasswordEncoder gatPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PlaintextPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('admin')")
                .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", false)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

}
```

}

Сервер запускается, но падает 500 ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager ru.ks_on_v.service.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Друг, ты серьезно? Первая же ссылке в гугле по твоему запросу ведет в [документацию по Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html), где подробно описано что и как в Java конфиге.

Comment: Я это читал.
Создал метод configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth). Для чтения пользователей и ролей с бд.
В нем использовал configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth).
При этом обьявил глобальную переменную 
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
На нее ругается ide: No beans of DataSource type found.

Comment: а DataSource у тебя существует? Он компонент Spring?

Comment: Да. Он у меня в конфигурации БД.
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {

Comment: В ошибке написано, что Spring не смог создать компонент с именем "securityServiceImpl", т.к. не смог заинжектить в него бин AuthenticationManager (через @Autowire). Т.к. не нашел кандидатов.